# Firing a mouseleave event only if it lasts longer than a few seconds long - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, delay, mouseleave

I created a slide on that fires when the user attempts to leave the page(mouseleave towards the tabs/url).  The problem is that it fires immediately and can be quite annoying when doing so, therefore...

I thought of using setTimeout and clearTimeout to delay a firing of the event until only 500ms after the mouseleave event occurs and only if they stay there for the duration.

**That means, I want that the event fires ONLY if the user mouseleaves for longer than 500ms. Otherwise if they return before the duration, the event doesn't fire..**

**To produce the slide-out.  Make sure you click in the document and then scroll out towards the top**

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/daneiswork/2fgh3c6w/32/)

**JS**

```
$(() => {
  // Sliding helper nav initial position hidden
  function showSidebar() {
    $('.nav__slide').removeClass('hidden_nav__slide');
    $('.nav__slide').animate({
      right: '0px',
    }, {
      queue: false,
      duration: 800,
    });
    $('body').addClass('overlay');
  }


  // Limiting mouse events from firing too often.
  function handleMouseOut(e) {
    function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    let timeout;
      return (...args) => {
        const context = this;
        const later = () => {
          timeout = null;
          if (!immediate) {
            func.apply(context, args);
          }
        };

        const callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
      };
    }
    const event = e || window.event;
    const from = event.relatedTarget || event.toElement;
    // Handling when the mouseover is outside of the clientY (in the browser/tab area above)
    // but not outside of the browser window

    if ((!from || from.nodeName === 'HTML') && event.clientY <= 0) {
      debounce(showSidebar, 1000, true)();
    }
  }

  // Hiding the sliding helper div after the user clicks the close button.
  function hideSidenav() {
    $('body').removeClass('overlay');

    setTimeout(() => {
      $('.nav__slide').addClass('hidden_nav__slide');
    }, 700);


    $('.nav__slide').animate({
      right: '-450px',
    }, {
      queue: false,
      duration: 800,
    });
  }



  // Closing button to hide the sliding helper nav.
  $('.js__button__close').click(() => {
    hideSidenav();
    document.removeEventListener('mouseout', handleMouseOut);
  });




  // Initializing the event.
  function init() {
    if (document.addEventListener) {
      document.addEventListener('mouseout', handleMouseOut, false);
    }
  }

  init()
});
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="nav__slide">
        <font class="js__button__close button__close" color="red"></font>
        <div class="logo-line"></div>

        <h2 class="content-header">Words to return!</h2>


      </div>

      <h2 class="heading">A main title </h2>
      <main class="main-content">
        <ul>

          <li>some words here</li>
        </ul>


      </main>

      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </div>
</div>
</body>


 </html>
```

**CSS**

```
.nav__slide {
  /* Positioning */
  position: fixed;
  /* Visuals */
  background: #ffffff;
  /* Positioning */
  top: 0;
  right: -450px;
  width: 390px;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
  /* Box-Model and Display */
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.nav__slide .button__close {
  /* Visuals */
  background: #ffffff;
  /* Box-Model and Display */
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
}

.nav__slide .button__close:before {
  /* Box-Model and Display */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 20%;
  content: "\2715";
}

.hidden_nav__slide {
  /* Visuals */
  visibility: hidden;
}

.nav__slide .content-container {
  /* Box-Model and Display */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  /* Typography */
  font-weight: 400;
}

.nav__slide .content__logo {
  /* Box-Model and Display */
  width: 170px;
  height: 60px;
}

.nav__slide .logo-line {
  /* Visuals */
  border-bottom: solid #dbdbdb 2px;
  border-style: ridge;
  opacity: 0.1;
  /* Box-Model and Display */
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: -1%;
}

.nav__slide .content-header {
  /* Positioning */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /* Typography */
  font-weight: 200;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  /* Box-Model and Display */
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  margin-top: 25%;
}

/* This will likely be removed depending
on the image that is used */

.nav__slide .stand-in-image {
  /* Box-Model and Display */
  width: 240px;
  height: 140px;
}

.nav__slide .content-container__header {
  /* Typography */
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
  /* Box-Model and Display */
  margin-left: 20%;
}

.nav__slide .content-list__item {
  /* Typography */
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 26px;
  font-size: 15px;
  /* Box-Model and Display */
  display: flex;
  padding: 2%;
  margin-left: 10%;
}

.nav__slide .coupon-button {
  /* Typography */
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Visuals */
  background-color: #b2ca48;
  /* Box-Model and Display */
  padding: 10%;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

.nav__slide .main-content {
  /* Positioning */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  z-index: 0;
}

/* Adding the overlay:after class onto the body  */

.overlay:after {
  /* Box-Model and Display */
  content: "";
  /* Positioning */
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* Visuals */
  opacity: 0.9;
  background-color: #373737be;
  /* Positioning */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

I found a few other answers that do something similar to what I was thinking when it comes to delaying the firing of an event.

[Example One](http://jsfiddle.net/daneiswork/qGRcH/209/)
[Example Two](http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/3YBr8/5/)

I have been tooling around with it but due to the code being older (a few months back) and that i'm still relatively new.  I'm learning the lesson of needing to: 
-Make better comments as to what is doing what
-Make sure to know what code you're using thoroughly when constructing a solution.

Thank you for your help and i'll continue to try and tweak it but not finding anything concrete that works.

Comment: Your fiddle is incomplete `all.js` not found.  Can you reproduce *just the issue* in a code snippet in your question?  Have a read of [mcve].

Comment: The fiddle is working on my side.  Not sure why it wouldn't be going.  I'll take a look and check that out.  Thanks!
*edited the fiddle.  maybe works now for you?

Comment: Do you want to slide when the user stay in the outside of the page for 500ms? or just triggering the after 500ms?

Comment: Fixed the all.js - `not found http://fiddle.jshell.net/daneiswork/2fgh3c6w/24/show/style.css`

Comment: I was trying to have the slide out happen only after the mouse is outside for 500ms.  So if they leave and come back into the window before 500ms then it doesn't fire.  Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: Did you check the arguments of your own code:  `debounce(showSidebar, 1000, true)();`  `debounce(func, wait, immediate)`  - just reading the parameter names (not even what they do) fixed the issue.

Comment: @freedomn-m can i ask if you're clicking on the jsfiddle link I provided?  I've gone to it both times and it's produces the slide.  I'm not sure why you're having a problem with it?  Definitely can be my fault but wanted to ask.

Comment: I think you already find an answer in Example One. Is that what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/3tu9yonh/

Comment: It works (now I know how to trigger what you're testing) - just gives errors.

Comment: Anyway, just change `immediate` to `false`: http://jsfiddle.net/2fgh3c6w/30/

Comment: But then it just fires after 500ms?  I'm wanting it to fire only if they stay out there 500ms and if they come back in then it doesn't fire.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @Ballsigno That is what i'm going for.  I'm having a problem implementing into my code.  Which is more of a user (aka my) problem as i'm not understanding how to best implement it.

Comment: @Ballsigno if you have any insight in how to implement into my current code, i'd greatly appreciate.  Because I understand what you posted as it's similar to what I already posted as an example. The problem is where and how with my code.  Not to show what I have already found.  Thanks!

Comment: *"The problem is that it fires immediately"* / *"I'm wanting it to fire only if they stay out there 500ms"* - this is **not in the question** - How are we supposed to know that you don't want it to fire if they re-enter?   Please update the question with a *clear (and complete) description of the problem*.

Comment: In your code that says "if they've moved out show sidebar" you need to add an "else hide sidebar".  But you'll also need to cancel the debounce and possibly handle the mouse event parameters differently.  Might be easier to write if you stuck with *either* jquery *or* javascript event handlers and didn't nest the debounce.

Comment: That's what I was thinking when it comes to problem of what to do.  Hmmm. Yeah, i'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Comment: @daneiswork Really? just apply it, if you won't get an answer in a few hours from someone, I'll come back.

Comment: @Ballsigno sorry to disappoint but yes, really.  I'll continue trying.  I appreciate it regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I could do it.
I don't quite understand what you mean by a variable, `immediate`, though.
Also, I cut your code a bit, but it's fine, I think.

```
// Timer
let timer;
// Called, when mouse enter to the document.
function handleMouseEnter() {
    // clear timer(stop).
    clearTimeout(timer);
}

// Limiting mouse events from firing too often.
function handleMouseLeave() {
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        // Show side bar.
        showSidebar();
        // Event off. (ShowSideBar will run only once.)
        $(document)
            .off('mouseleave', handleMouseLeave)
            .off('mouseenter', handleMouseEnter);
    }, 500);
}

// Initializing the event.
function init() {
    // the same as document.addEventListener('mouseleave~
    $(document)
        .on('mouseleave', handleMouseLeave)
        .on('mouseenter', handleMouseEnter);
}
```

[For Example](https://jsfiddle.net/ymtva6dn/)

**UPDATED**

```
// Limiting mouse events from firing too often.
function handleMouseLeave(e) {
    // you can get original event.
    console.log(e.originalEvent);
```

Comment: I appreciate it.  I see now I didn't say how I wanted it to only happen when the user goes above the document.  I'm currently trying to implement the part as below is.  So that it fires only when it goes above and not to the left or right or bottom.  

  if ((!from || from.nodeName === 'HTML') && event.clientY <= 0) {
      debounce(showSidebar, 1000, true)();
    }
  }

Comment: Oh, so, that `if statement` had meaning. I didn't notice, but I'm glad I could be of help.

Comment: Yeah.  I'll see if I can figure it out.  Appreciate it greatly.

Comment: Since I changed the way of implement using jQuery, I added some tips for you.(Updated my answer)

Comment: Okay. great. Thanks so much!